# Java "package does not exist" error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, importerror

I'm using Android Studio (v 1.2.2) with Java Platform (JDK) release 8u45 for Android App development. At the moment I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string with base 64 encoding by importing the following as such::

```
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

However, after trying to import `java.util.Base64.Encoder,` I got the error

```
Error:(30, 24) error: package java.util.Base64 does not exist
```

at compile time. I then tried to import `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` for base 64 encoding and got a similar error. I tried updating Android studio (to what it is now, v 1.2.2) and updating Java JDK (to its current 8u45). If somebody could offer a pointer as to why these import statements aren't recognized it would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your minSdk?

Comment: also, there is no `java.util.Base64` in android.

Comment: nor `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`

Comment: @njzk2 The accepted answer solved the problem but if its still relevant my minSdk is 12

Comment: @Novice it is relevant because android.util.Base64 was added in API 8, which means that you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android API ships with its own Base64 utility which can be found under `android.util.Base64`. If this import does not work, there is a problem with your project setup.

Here is a quick working example:

```
String data = Base64.encode(new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

More Information:
[Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)